# javascript function calling inside a page_load event of asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, function

How can i call a javascript function in the page_load event of a asp.net c# web application

I also want to pass a variable to that javascript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version of .NET you should use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript
```

the Page level method is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is client-side code.

Page_Load is server-side code.

You can't call one directly from the other.  The next best thing is to arrange for your client-side code to be called when the page loads in the browser.  You can do that by dynamically generating your script in-line with the rest of your markup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Page.RegisterStartUpScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)

```
  public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    if (!this.IsStartupScriptRegistered("Startup"))
    {
      // Form the script to be registered at client side.
      String scriptString = "<script language=\"JavaScript\"> function DoClick() {";
      scriptString += "showMessage2.innerHTML='<h4>Welcome to Microsoft .NET!</h4>'}";
      scriptString += "function Page_Load(){ showMessage1.innerHTML=";
      scriptString += "'<h4>RegisterStartupScript Example</h4>'}<";
      scriptString += "/";
      scriptString += "script>";
      this.RegisterStartupScript("Startup", scriptString);
    }
```